# Unable to use GKE Autopilot for Window pods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've experimented with several methods to deploy Windows pods in GKE Autopilot, but encountered the following issues:

1. Using the node selector:

```yaml
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      ...
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: windows
```

Result: Although resources are created in Kubernetes, the pods never reach a 'Running' state due to the absence of suitable nodes for scheduling.

2. Specifying the OS directly:

```yaml
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      ...
      os: windows
```

Result: I received an error regarding securityContext properties, which are not allowed when the schema includes spec.template.spec.os = "windows.

3. Applying node affinity:

```yaml
...
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      ...
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/os
            operator: In
            values:
            - windows
```

Result: Similar to the first method, while resources are created, the pods fail to reach a 'Running' state due to node scheduling constraints.

Any insights or solutions to address these challenges would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a Windows node available?

Comment: I can't add node myself in Autopilot. Autopilot automatically creates nodes for Linux pods but not for Windows. I'm seeking a solution for this. There is not windows nodes because, Autopilot is not creating them

Comment: That means you will need to launch a K8s cluster.

Comment: GKE autopilot is linux only. I didn't find a clear documentation on it, except this page that talk about only about Linux stuff: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-security

Answer (score 0):

GKE Autopilot supports Linux Only for now https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/resources/autopilot-standard-feature-comparison